# Graphics.DrawString doesn't print a text

Tags: c#, graphics, draw, dpi, drawstring

I have this line of code:

```
graphics.DrawString(valoreOggetto, textFont, brush, textContainer, stringFormat);
```

where I have:

- valoreOggetto: a simple casual word;
- textFont: in which I use 'Arial' and the FontSize is 70 (with an Height of 135)
- brush: I think that is useless for this question;
- textContainer: it depends on the DPI (I will give the measures later)
- stringFormat: in which I have as FormatFlags: FitBlackBox,NoWrap and LineLimit

this are the parameters.
The problem is that if I have a container with a small height, the word inside is printed if the DPI is under 75.
I mean, I want that the word is always printed and if the container's height is smaller than the word's height, the word will be cut in some parts.
For instance, the measure for the two DPIs are:

- DPI = 75 -> {X=33,Y=,47,Width=203,Height=72}
- DPI = 300 -> {X=132,Y=189,Width=814,Height=289}

The thing that I can't understand is that if I enlarge the container's height the print of the text will always work, while with these measures it works only with some DPIs.